# Welcome file not displayed in my Dynamic web project

Tags: html, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, welcome-file

I am trying to create sample web project to understand the concept. I am facing some issues.
After executing the application on `Java web server`, Welcome list page doesn't get displayed.

When i googled , basic reason , I found is location of `index.html` is incorrect or it is not mentioned in `web.xml` file. In my case , I think it is correct.

Please Guide.
following are the screen shots.

[image: '404 not FOund]

[image]

Regards

Prat

---

Edit :

[image: Server Info]

Comment: Have you tried just going to the naked url? `localhost:8080/`

Comment: What kind of server is this, and how are you running it?

Comment: is it working if you give the full path like, http://localhost:8080/weatherapp3/index.html

Comment: @nitind : this java server by sap See the Link https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-java-eclipse-setup.html   ; I have attached the screen shot as well

Comment: @Sudhakar : no.

Comment: @GameBuilder is your hello servlet working?

Comment: For the example, you can refer the https://github.com/sudhakarbadugu/ServeltTutorial. It is working fine in Tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

**welcome-file-list in web.xml**

The welcome-file-list element of web-app, is used to define a list of welcome files. Its sub element is welcome-file that is used to define the welcome file.

A welcome file is the file that is invoked automatically by the server, if you don't specify any file name.

By default server looks for the welcome file in following order:

1. welcome-file-list in web.xml
2. index.html
3. index.htm
4. index.jsp

If none of these files are found, server renders 404 error.

If you have specified welcome-file in web.xml, and all the files index.html, index.htm and index.jsp exists, priority goes to welcome-file.

If welcome-file-list entry doesn't exist in web.xml file, priority goes to index.html file then index.htm and at last index.jsp file.

```
 <web-app>      
  <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>  
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Now, home.html and default.html will be the welcome files.

If you have the welcome file, you can directory invoke the project as given below:

http://localhost:8080/projectname

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have done exactly the same. you can see the screen shot.